# Implicit conversion between datatypes

Tags: c++, type-conversion

Why does, for example, the result of operation between an `unsigned short` and `int` always yields an `int`?

```
unsigned short s = 65535;
int i = 65535
```

Expression `typeid(s * i * i).name()`, gives a value which is out of the range of an `int` but still the implicit conversion returns an `int`, why?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There are a set of conversions called the [usual arithmetic conversions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/09ka8bxx.aspx) that are used prior to the evaluation of most arithmetic operators.

Basically, you can consider there to be a few rules for arithmetic on integers:

- First, integer arithmetic is never performed with operands "smaller than" `int`, so in the case of `short * signed char`, both the `short` and the `signed char` operands are promoted to `int`, the two `int` values are multiplied, and then the result is an `int`.
- Second, if one or both of the types are "larger than" `int`, the compiler selects a type that is at least "as large" as the type of the largest operand.  So, if you have `long * int`, the `int` is promoted to a `long` and the result is a `long`.
- Third, if either operand is `unsigned`, then the result is unsigned.  So, if you have `long * unsigned int`, the `long` and the `unsigned int` are both promoted to an `unsigned long` and the result is an `unsigned long`.

If either operand has floating point type, then floating point arithmetic is performed:  `float`, `double`, or `long double` is used (which one depends on the types of the operands; the full table used to determine the result type can be found on the page linked at the beginning of this answer).

Note that *the result type is not dependent upon the values of the operands*. The type has to be selected by the compiler at compile time, before the values are known.

If the result of `s * i * i` is out of range of the result type (`int`, in your scenario), then you're out of luck:  your program can't decide at runtime, "oh, I should switch to use a `long`!" because the result type had to be selected at compile time.